# starting service without application

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a call blocking application. It has 3 files:

1. class BlockMyCall extends BroadcastReceiver
2. class SimpleClass1 extends Service
3. PhoneBlock extends Activity

I start "PhoneBlock " Activity to call Service "SimpleClass1", which eventually calls "BlockMyCall" intended to block outbound calls (by setting result to "null").

I want to know if I can run the class1 from service without starting activity. If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Put a broadcast receiver to READ_PHONE_STATE and on receiving this broadcast ,start the service.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest you can specify the receiver to start at boot like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="ProjectMonitorServiceManager"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="ProjectMonitorServiceManager">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I'm not 100% sure that is what your looking to achieve or not.